# Precision in C++

Tags: c++, sql, decimal, concatenation

I have this query in my C++ code:

```
 query << "UPDATE currency SET value= " << currencyValue
```

currencyValue is defined as "`const double& currencyValue`" and when I watch the value is

```
0.00045545105422339915
```

But if I check the value of the query then I get something like this

```
UPDATE currency SET value = 0.000455451
```

so decimals get missing...

Any ideas why?

Comment: What type is query? A std::stringstream?

Comment: This looks like a formidable way to get an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (probably not when `currencyValue` is a numeric type, but if you have this, then you probably also have other instances of creating SQL query strings this way).

Comment: The typw of query is wostringstream

Comment: Why not use currency as an int representing the number of cents?

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but: Are you aware that "currency" and "floating point" are a really bad combination? Currency should always with no exceptions operate on big integers. You would not want that a million times one dollar in yen is different from a million dollars in yen. However, this is _exactly_ what will happen.

Comment: Damon, you are right, but that was just an example... the real query is much bigger... maybe I should have chosen a better one

Comment: It does not have anything to do with the size, it's a matter of principle. Let me explain (I will use `float`, because it is more obvious, but the same applies for `double` too). A float can _only_ hold sums of fractional values of powers of two, not _any arbitrary_ value. For example you can store 0.5 or 0.25 or (0.5+0.25) or (0.25+0.001953125). Storing 0.251, 0.26 or 0.261 is not possible, you can only approximate them. Also, a float has 9 significant decimals (double has 17), no more. Which means that 1.25 = 1 + 0.25, but 100000000.25 = 10000000, which is bad karma for money.

Comment: Damon, I get it now. Thanks for the explantion. I'll take that in consideration if I need to use currencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try calling **[setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/)**(10) (or any value you actually want) on your stream before outputting the double value to it.

You can do it like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
query << "UPDATE currency SET value= " << std::setprecision(10) << currencyValue;
```

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that? I am new to C++

Comment: @Dave. You got it to work, but since you're new to C++, here is a good page to search for clues [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/).

Comment: @jetimms and @Als - thanks for the edits and comment - you've both improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

currencyValue is double, "UPDATE currency SET value= " is string. Precision is lost in conversion from double to string.
You can use something like "std::setprecision(20)" or use different function to convert double to string.